# updating a record based on a sum value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i have an item table that has an ID ,Product, cost  ,quantity and status field. what i want is to up date an item based on the sum of the quantity of the products where the ID is the same.

so for example

```
ID            Product             cost   quantity   status
1             computer            100     10
1             tablet              200     10
2             ipad                50      15
```

now when the supplier is delivering these items  i want when the quantity reaches 0 for the same Id the status must change to Received other than that it should say receiving.

eg if the supplier brings 2 computers the quantity will change to 8 and the status for ID 1 will say receiving, if the supplier brings 8 computers the status should still say receiving because the tablet has an outstanding balance of 10. but when the supplier brings 10 tablets and both ID 1 quantity is 0 the status for both should say received

```
ID            Product             cost   quantity   status
    1             computer            100     0         Received
    1             tablet              200     0         Received
    2             ipad                50      15
```

what i have tried is

```
UPDATE item
SET update_status =  CASE
                        when  sum (quantity) >0 THEN
                          'Receiving'
                        ELSE
                          'Received'
                     END
                     where approvalid =:p5_approvalid;
```

but i am getting group function is not allowed here

Comment: The "status" column is redundant (its value is fully determined by two other columns, id and quantity). As a matter of good business practices, it should not be stored. If you need that info very quickly, you can write a **view** (which doesn't store any data, it's just a saved query with a name given to it so you can reference it in other queries), so that the value of "received" or "receiving" can be calculated on-the-fly from the most current values in the other columns (especially "quantity"). Keeping the column in the stored table, with a trigger, etc. - that's just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I fully support mathguys comment. Also, reconsider your naming choices. A table column named `ID` better be a unique primary key.

If you still want to do this, use `MERGE`:

```
merge into item
using (
    select id, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
    from item
    group by id
) u
on (item.id = u.id)
when matched then update
    set status = case when sum_quantity > 0 then 'Receiving' else 'Received' end
```

The using clause will calculate the quantity sums by `ID`, this way it wont be necessary to use any aggregation function in the set clause.